# How to create json annotated POJO class

Tags: json, eclipse, jackson, pojo, fasterxml

I see some class like this in the code I am looking, and wonder how
it was generated, they looks like generated by a plugin or by eclipse itself, I know eclipse can create a POJO file for your through wizard, but how do I get results like below?

```
   public class Item implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3868244754652312286L;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;
    @JsonProperty("quantity")
    private String quantity;
    @JsonProperty("price")
    private String price;
    @JsonProperty("tax")
    private String tax;
    @JsonProperty("sku")
    private String sku;
    @JsonProperty("originalPrice")
    private String originalPrice;
    @JsonIgnore
    private HashMap<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

Comment: Not necessarily generated from the looks of it, aside from the generated UID.  However, please look into Swagger editor and swagger ui for Spring Framework API POJO generation.  This will differ from what you see an a few ways, mainly jdoc related.  Good luck!

Comment: thanks, but I forgot to mention there are tons of such files in the project I am looking, while it is possible, I just can't imagine manually creating so many classes